# Problema com verificação findOne

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Eu estou usando typeorm e postgres. No meu use case eu tenho um método execute:

```
  async execute({ name, email, password }: ICreateUserDTO): Promise<void> {
    const userExists = await this.usersRepository.findByEmail(email);

    if (userExists) {
      throw new Error(`User ${name} already exists`);
    }

    this.usersRepository.create({ name, email, password });
  }
}
```

No meu repositório:

```
  async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.repository.findOne({ email });
    return user;
  }
```

Consigo criar um usuário normalmente, porém se o email já existe ele não me deixa criar mais nenhum usuário, mesmo com email diferente. Sempre retornando o mesmo erro

```
Error: User admin already exists
app             |     at CreateUserUseCase.<anonymous> (/usr/app/src/modules/users/useCases/createUser/CreateUserUseCase.ts:13:13)
app             |     at step (/usr/app/src/modules/users/useCases/createUser/CreateUserUseCase.ts:33:23)
app             |     at Object.next (/usr/app/src/modules/users/useCases/createUser/CreateUserUseCase.ts:14:53)
app             |     at fulfilled (/usr/app/src/modules/users/useCases/createUser/CreateUserUseCase.ts:5:58)
app             |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
app             | [ERROR] 22:48:59 Error: User admin already exists
```

Comment: O que `this.repository.findOne` retorna nesse caso? O que eu entendi é que por causa desse `Promise<User>` ele retorna algum objeto, mesmo se o `email` não existir. Não sei se deveria ser algo como `Promise<User | null>`, para caso `email` não exista, ele retorne `null`,. mas é só um palpite.

Answer (score -1):

No método findByEmail do usersRepository pode trocar o findOne por find, visto que o campo email é um campo de valor unico, dessa forma:

```
this.repository.find({
   where: {
      email
   }
})
```

O que provavelmente está ocorrendo é, a função findOne está retornando o primeiro registro da tabela sem aplicar o filtro.

Sugiro também dar um log no userExists().

segue a documentação oficial:
https://typeorm.biunav.com/en/repository-api.html#repository-api

Comment: Considere adicionar referências a documentações do TypeORM que sustentem suas afirmações, assim outras pessoas no futuro podem se beneficiar da sua resposta :).

Comment: obrigado pelo toque @RuanMontelo!

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).